# Comparing ObjectID's in Jade and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, variables, comparison, pug, objectid

Jade Template Code

```
    each member in team.members
      if member == user._id
       - flag=true;
```

Here, team is a document in the collection 'teams' in Mongo DB, and 'members' is a property having Arrays as value.

Here values of #{member} are `53fecc27bace957811633dcc` and `5412a08fa51c105017b9f1fe` respectively. Both are Object Id's.

Value of #{user.id} is `53fecc27bace957811633dcc`

However, this comparison returns as false and flag is never set to true.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED FOR CLARITY:

The mongodb-native driver uses a custom ObjectID type. Even if the ObjectIDs are the same, `member` and `user._id` would still refer to two distinct objects, and therefore the comparison fails.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm talking about. In the example below I have a constructor function for a `TestObject` (simulating the mongo `ObjectID`). I instantiate two objects (i.e. `x1` and `x2`) both with the same parameter. While `x1` and `x2` are instances of the same object and both were created with the same arguments, they are actually just two different objects with the same data/payload. Therefore, the first direct comparison fails, because they in fact are not the same. To take the simulation a bit further, I added a prototype method `.equals()` which ensures that both objects are instances of TestObject and the payloads are identical.

```
function TestObject(data) {
    this.payload = data;
}
TestObject.prototype.equals = function(anotherObject) {
    return (anotherObject instanceof TestObject) && (this.payload === anotherObject.payload);  
};

var x1 = new TestObject(1), x2 = new TestObject(1);

console.log(x1 == x2); // <-- false
console.log(x1.equals(x2)); // <-- true
```

You can compare them by converting the ObjectIDs to strings.

```
each member in team.members
  if member.toString() == user._id.toString()
   - flag=true;
```

Another possible solution would be to use the ObjectId `.equal()` method:

```
each member in team.members
  if member.equals(user._id)
   - flag=true;
```

Comment: A reason will be appreciated on why the earlier scenario didn't work.

Comment: I assume you're using Mongoose, which uses the mongodb-native driver. The mongodb-native driver uses a custom ObjectID type. Even if the ObjectIDs are the same, `member` and user._id` refer to two distinct objects, and therefore the comparison fails. There are only two ways to compare these custom ObjectIDs: (1) the `.equals()` method (e.g. `member.equals(user._id)`), or (2) using `.toString()` which I demonstrated in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB objectIds are probably not simple strings. As per [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-objectid), they are BSON types.
It's possible that member and user._id are two different objects that is why a "reference equals" comparison is failing, even though their string representations are the same.

On a related note, it's a bad idea to use MongoDB generated object IDs in your application. A more robust design would be to have your own identifier for every record type.

Comment: So if I store an object id in another object say x, you mean to say  x is no longer an objectid?

Comment: What @Aniket Lawande was trying to say that, while both objects are still ObjectIDs and as far as Mongoose is concerned they represent the same ObjectID, as far as JavaScript (hence Jade) is concerned they are two different Objects, even if they are of the same type and have the same payload (the ObjectID reference). I edited my original answer to simulate the issue with a simple custom object.